# Reddit to Twitter bot having issues with key-dictionary calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, twitter, praw

So I'm following the tutorial of a certain reddit to twitter bot thats coded in python using PRAW and I am stuck hitting errors.

Running this code in the command console gives me the error on line 74

```
import praw
import json
import requests
import tweepy
import time

access_token = 'secret'
access_token_secret = ' secret'
consumer_key = 'secret'
consumer_secret = 'secret'

def strip_title(title):
    if len(title) < 94:
        return title
    else:
        return title[:93] + "..."

def tweet_creator(subreddit_info):
    post_dict = {}
    post_ids = []
    print "[bot] Getting posts from Reddit"
    for submission in subreddit_info.get_hot(limit=20):
        post_dict[strip_title(submission.title)] = submission.url
        post_ids.append(submission.id)
    print "[bot] Generating short link using goo.gl"
    mini_post_dict = {}
    for post in post_dict:
        post_title = post
        post_link = post_dict[post]         
        short_link = shorten(post_link)
        mini_post_dict[post_title] = short_link 
    return mini_post_dict, post_ids

def setup_connection_reddit(subreddit):
    print "[bot] setting up connection with Reddit"
    r = praw.Reddit('yasoob_python reddit twitter bot '
                'monitoring %s' %(subreddit)) 
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(subreddit)
    return subreddit

def shorten(url):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = {"longUrl": url}
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    link = json.loads(r.text)
    return link

def duplicate_check(id):
    found = 0
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if id in line:
                found = 1
    return found

def add_id_to_file(id):
    with open('posted_posts.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(id) + "\n")

def main():
    subreddit = setup_connection_reddit('showerthoughts')
    post_dict, post_ids = tweet_creator(subreddit)
    tweeter(post_dict, post_ids)

def tweeter(post_dict, post_ids):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    for post, post_id in zip(post_dict, post_ids):
        found = duplicate_check(post_id)
        if found == 0:
            print "[bot] Posting this link on twitter"
            print post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #Python #reddit #bot"
            api.update_status(post+" "+post_dict[post]+" #Python #reddit #bot")
            add_id_to_file(post_id)
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            print "[bot] Already posted" 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error :

```
print post+" "+post_dict[post]+"#python #reddit #bot"
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

My understanding of the code and error is that it needs a string to be send but is somehow getting the entire key-dictionary set. I thought by sending the [post] parameter into post_dict that it will be able to get the certain post for the bot to utalize, but instead, its fetching the dictionary!

There are two lines, 74 and 75 that both call post_dict[post] and is not utalizing the dictionary's value when calling post key.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `post` and `post_dict` before you call that concatenation in the the `tweeter` function's For loop. That should show you what those structs look like and make the solution evident.